# How many distinct transitive actions exis in a cyclic group of order $n.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

The number of distinct transitive actions should depend on the number of orders possible for $g\in G= C_n$.

Say, take $n=12:$

Hence, the answer as per Lagrange's theorem should be: $6$, as orders of $g$ possible are: $\{1, 2, 3,4, 6, 12\}.$

Comment: You have the correct set of numbers, but you need to A) describe an action of all of $C_{12}$ on a set $X$ of each of those sizes, and B) explain why the cardinality of $X$ determines the transitive action uniquely up to isomorphism.

Comment: Hint: By the orbit-stabilizer theorem it is really not so much a question of orders of elements of $G$. Rather, it is about the indices of subgroups $H\le G$. The gist of orbit-stabilizer is that any transitive action is isomorphic to the action on the set of cosets $G/H$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Not read the topic till now. Next week has the topic of orbits-stabilizers. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: There is  a general result that, for any group $G$,  there is a bijection between the equivalence classes of transitive actions of $G$, and the set of conjugacy classes of subgroups of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks a lot. Link for reference, or here any question. Also, any suggestions for my answer. Actually, not sure if your last comment gives same result of  $6$.

Comment: This bijection is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568361). Yes, it gives the same result, because $C_{12}$ has exactly six subgroups. (The group is abelian, so each subgroup forms a single conjugacy class of subgroups.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That there's only $6$ conjugacy classes of subgroups in $C_{12}$ implies that there's only $6$ possible transitive actions. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1568361/1070376).

In general, for the cyclic group $C_n$, it's going to be $\sigma_0(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d^0$, the number of divisors of $n$.  Here $\sigma $ is [the divisor function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). Because a cyclic group has a characteristic subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor of $n$.  Since it's characteristic,  the size of its conjugacy class is one.

We're using that the number of transitive actions of $G$ is the number of conjugacy classes of subgroups of $G$, as in the first link.

Comment: With some limitations. For example, if $|X|\le 3$, the trivial kernel is ruled out.

Comment: True.  There's at most $6$.  @fitzcarraldo

Comment: Please show one example of conjugate subgroups here, being equal. Needed infact to understand how to solve; https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4504636/424260

Comment: @jiten see this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1555108/1070376

Comment: Request help in post stated in my last comment.