# Find sizes of disjoint subsets to make transitive action by icosahedron on set $X$.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Could only prepare ground for this in my last post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4505185/424260), with a reduced group and set size.

Kindly give hints, as sizes of subsets that can think of are too small: $X_3.$ Though read of tetrahedron too, but not clear where the fourth vertex will lie.
Also,the subsets have to be disjoint; so if $X_4$ is taken then $X_3$ is removed.

Comment: The group of symmetries in particular acts by isometries, so if $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is in the same orbit as $\{v_1',v_2'\}$ then $d(v_1,v_2)=d(v_1',v_2')$. Thus the level sets of $d$ partition $X$ into $G$-invariant subsets. Now can you check whether $d(v_1,v_2)=d(v_1',v_2')$ implies there is $g\in G$ sending $\{v_1,v_2\}$ to $\{v_1',v_2'\}$? If not, you may have to subdivide your partition further.

Comment: @DavidSheard Please note that by now Orbits not covered. But, next week has it. So can read, though not expected. But, request more details/elaboration.

Comment: OK, I'm not using any special properties of orbits like the Orbit Stabiliser Theorem (although if you had met this it might help), I'm just using the terminology. By "$\{v_1,v_2\}$  is in the same orbit as $\{v'_1,v'_2\}$" I merely mean "there exists $g\in G$ such that $g\star\{v_1,v_2\}=\{v'_1,v'_2\}$.

Comment: @DavidSheard Sorry, it was easy. Also, what is meant by: "level sets of $d$ ".

Comment: @DavidSheard If not totally incorrect, checking for $2.60.66 $ actions is infeasible. Or, you imply some shortcut.

Comment: "Level set" is just a fancy way to say $\left\{\{v_1,v_2\}\mid d(v_1,v_2)=c\right\}$ for some fixed $c\in\mathbb{R}^{\ge0}$. Ie the set of all pairs of vertices which are some fixed distance apart.

Comment: I don't know what you mean? Isn't there just a single action in your question: that of the symmetry group of the icosahedron on the icosahedron?

Comment: @DavidSheard There is a single action. But the verb of 'applying a symmetry to both vertices in a pair simultaneously', occurs for each symmetry (which are $2.60$) and each pair (which are $66$). Please tell where wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall expand on the hints I provided in the comments. First note that any symmetry of the icosahedron preserves distances, and so if the pair of vertices $\{u,v\}$ get transformed into $$g\star\{u,v\}=\{g\star u,g\star v\}=:\{u',v'\},$$ then $d(u,v)=d(u',v')$.

Suppose therefore that we have a partition $X=X_1\sqcup\cdots\sqcup X_k$ such that $G$ acts transitively on each $X_i$. Then the observation above implies that if $\{u,v\},\{u',v'\}\in X_i$ for some $i$, then $d(u,v)=d(u',v')$. I claim that taking exactly the partition of $X$ coming from $d$ is sufficient.

In order to prove this, let $X_i=\{\{u,v\}\mid d(u,v)=c\}$ for some fixed $c$. Let $\{u,v\},\{u',v'\}\in X_i$. Now, a key observation is that while $G$ may not act transitively on $X$, it does act transitively on the set of vertices of the dodecahedron. Therefore we can find $g\in G$ such that $g\star u'=u$.

If we define $w=g\star v'$ then we can reduce to the case we have $\{u,v\},\{u,w\}\in X_i$, and want to show that there is $h\in G$ such that $h\star\{u,v\}=\{u,w\}$. Such an $h$ must lie in the stabiliser of $u$, $\textrm{Stab}_G(u)$. By considering a picture of  an icosahedron, t is easy to convince yourself (by putting $u$ at the top say), then $\textrm{Stab}_G(u)$ acts transitively on the set of all vertices a fixed distance from $u$.

Thus, the required $h$ exists, and the element $gh$ maps $\{u,v\}\mapsto\{u,w\}$ as required.

[image]

(Image by [DTR](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Icosahedron.svg) (CC BY-SA 3.0))

This picture also shows that there are three possible distances for a pair of points to be apart, which I'm calling $d_1, d_2,d_3$. Let $X_1, X_2,X_3$ be the corresponding sets.

Finally we must compute the cardinalities of these sets. $|X_1|$ is the number of edges in the icosahedon, ie $\frac{20\times 3}{2}=30$. $|X_3|$ is the number of antipodal vertices, ie $\frac{20\times 3}{5\times 2}=6$. This leaves $|X_2|=|X|-|X_1|-|X_3|=30$.

Comment: Why it is that only three types of edges are there?

Comment: Look at the picture. Once the vertex $u$ is fixed every vertex is either one of the dark blue vertices, one of the purple vertices, or the red vertex. All vertices of the same colour are the same distance from $u$, so there are only three possible distances.

Comment: What property was used in getting number of edges as $= $ number of triangles $\cdot\frac 32.$ Also, why $X_1$ is for a different quantity (edges), while $X_2$ is about vertices.

Comment: Each of the 20 triangles contributes 3 edges, but this double counts the edges since when the triangles are glued together two edges get identified, hence $20\times 3/2$. $X_1$ corresponds the the dark blue vertices which are exactly one edge away from $u$. Thus the pairs of vertices in $X_1$ correspond the the edges in the icosahedron. Meanwhile $X_3$ corresponds to the red vertex which is antipodal to $u$. They are just different ways to describe the relationships between pairs of vertices in the picture. The number of antipodal pairs of vertices is half the number of vertices.